# Syntax error: Illegal return statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am getting a really weird JavaScript error when I run this code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
var ask = confirm('".$message."');
if (ask == false)
{
    return false;     
}

else
{
    return true;
}
</script>
```

In the JavaScript console it says:

`Syntax Error: Illegal return statement`

It occurs at `return true;` and `return false;`

(I am echoing this javascript from a php function; the `$message` variable is one of the php parameters)

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Return-statements are only allowed inside of functions. What are you hoping to achieve with the return-statements in your example?

Comment: For people Googling this issue, you can also get this error if you are missing a `{` or `}`.

Comment: > The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
> be returned to the function caller. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: @Gavin or equivalently have an extra stray { or }

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`return` only makes sense inside a function. There is no function in your code.

Also, your code is worthy if the Department of Redundancy Department. Assuming you move it to a proper function, this would be better:

```
return confirm(".json_encode($message).");
```

EDIT much much later: Changed code to use `json_encode` to ensure the message contents don't break just because of an apostrophe in the message.

Comment: ah...oops...since i was writing this inside a php function i was trying to return values. thanks for your help :)

Comment: that would not be better in the context of my code...i cant even be bothered to explain why; it's so incredibly complicated

Answer (score 6):

If you want to return some value then wrap your statement in function

```
function my_function(){ 

 return my_thing; 
}
```

Problem is with the statement on the 1st line if you are trying to use PHP

```
var ask = confirm ('".$message."');
```

IF you are trying to use PHP you should use

```
 var ask = confirm (<?php echo "'".$message."'" ?>); //now message with be the javascript string!!
```

Answer (score 6):

in javascript return statement only used inside function block. if you try to use return statement inside independent if else block it trigger syntax error : Illegal return statement in JavaScript

Here is my example code to avoid such error :

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
(function(){
    var ss= 'no';
    if(getStatus(ss)){
        alert('Status return true');   
    }else{
        alert('Status return false'); 
    }

    function getStatus(ask){
        if(ask=='yes')
        {
        return true;     
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
})();
</script>
```

Please check [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/so6upLsc/) example

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, most often this error message means that you have put an accidental closing brace somewhere, leaving the rest of your statements outside the function.

Example:

```
function a() {
    if (global_block) //syntax error is actually here - missing opening brace
       return;
    } //this unintentionally ends the function

    if (global_somethingelse) {
       //Chrome will show the error occurring here, 
       //but actually the error is in the previous statement
       return; 
    }

    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

where are you trying to return the value?
to console in dev tools is better for debugging

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
var ask = confirm('".$message."');
function answer(){
  if(ask==false){
    return false;     
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
console.log("ask : ", ask);
console.log("answer : ", answer());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just i forgot to declare the word 'function' before the function.
es

```
myFunc(num)
{
   if(num > 0)
      return;
}
```

this produce 'illegal return statement' error, becouse miss 'function' before myFunc(num)

correct form:

```
function myFunc(num)
{
    if(num > 0)
       return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in ES6 if you use the incorrect (older) syntax for static methods:

```
export default class MyClass
{
    constructor()
    {
       ...
    }

    myMethod()
    {
       ...
    }
}

MyClass.someEnum = {Red: 0, Green: 1, Blue: 2}; //works

MyClass.anotherMethod() //or
MyClass.anotherMethod = function()
{
   return something; //doesn't work
}
```

Whereas the correct syntax is:

```
export default class MyClass
{
    constructor()
    {
       ...
    }

    myMethod()
    {
       ...
    }

    static anotherMethod()
    {
       return something; //works
    }
}

MyClass.someEnum = {Red: 0, Green: 1, Blue: 2}; //works
```