# Sourcing Global Function from an Anonymous Function that Returns in Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, function, adobe, adobe-analytics

The below code snippets are not the actual code, they are only there to explain my issue. So please don't concentrate on the actual functionality. I'm working with Adobe DTM. I have no idea how to get an anonymous function that returns a value (as a Data Element to source a global function? If I have a normal anonymous function within my data Element, everything works fine. If the anonymous function returns, then it doesn't work? Is there any way to get this to work? Example:

```
//global function
function _myGlobalFunct(str){
return (str);
}
```

the following code of an anonymous function within the Data Element calls global function and it works as expected:

```
// working anonymous function
 (function () {
 window._myGlobalFunct("value1");
 })()
```

but the following return anonymous function, within the Data Element, doesn't call my function but doesn't throw any errors? :

```
// Not Working Properly but doesn't throw any errors?
return (function() { 
var rvalue = document.title || "No Title";
window._myGlobalFunct(rvalue);
return rvalue;
})();
```

I do know the function is executing but not getting any errors in Chrome?

Comment: Duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068278/syntax-error-illegal-return-statement-in-javascript When used in Chrome you will get an error with illegal return statement.

Comment: I was running mine in chrome and didn't get any errors. Also the question you mentioned that was a duplicate isn't similar to mine at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTM's data elements execute the code provided within a function (that may not be clear to the other users here), so there will be a `return` outside of a function in the code you input/show here. You're not returning the value from your function (or if you're trying to update `rvalue` within the function and `rvalue` isn't in the right scope (window vs. local)). In any case, is there a reason you're using the anonymous function anyways? Below should work:

```
var rvalue = document.title || "No Title";
return window._myGlobalFunct(rvalue);
```

If you still want the anonymous function, make sure to grab the return value from your function:

```
return (function() { 
  var rvalue = document.title || "No Title";
  return window._myGlobalFunct(rvalue);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can return a self-invoking function and then return again in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet I will explain it here in more detail, why it is indeed a duplicate. The first answer by Niet the Dark Absol in the link I mentioned above(for reference: [Syntax error: Illegal return statement in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068278/syntax-error-illegal-return-statement-in-javascript)), clearly says the following:

> `return` only makes sense inside a function. There is no function in
>   your code.

To apply this to your case:

```
return (function() {
```

Is your first line, if you would encapsulate everything in another function and call that one everything will be working fine, e.g.:

```
function myFunction(){
  return (function() { 
    var rvalue = document.title || "No Title";
    window._myGlobalFunct(rvalue);
    return rvalue;
  })();
}
```

And then you can call `myFunction()` to get your return value. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I only used these snippet, simplified examples to explain my situation. The global function is actually a helper function and the anonymous function would be a data element running inside Adobe DTM.